# How to apply format while typing UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to apply this format while Im typing in UITextField

Format: XXX-XXXXXXXXX-X-XX

I already have this format 'XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX' that was done like this, this also works when I erase digits.

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var cardTextField: UITextField!
private var isErasingTextField: Bool! = false

 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

  cardTextField.delegate = self
  cardTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeText(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)


 }

 @objc func didChangeText(textField: UITextField) {
    if let selectedRange = textField.selectedTextRange {
        let position = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
        /// This method is the mask to set format
        textField.cardstringFormat(positionOfEditing: position, erasing: isErasingTextField)
    }
 }


extension LoginViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

  public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    /// Important isErasingTextField
    isErasingTextField = range.length == 0 ? false : true

    guard let textFieldText = textField.text,
        let rangeOfTextToReplace = Range(range, in: textFieldText) else {
            return false
    }
    let substringToReplace = textFieldText[rangeOfTextToReplace]
    let count = textFieldText.count - substringToReplace.count + string.count

    return count <= 15
  }


}
```

This is an UITextField Extension:

```
 extension UITextField { 
  
  /// Method to set card format
  func cardstringFormat(positionOfEditing: Int? = nil, erasing: Bool? = nil) {
    guard let text = text else {return}
    let trimmedString = text.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).joined()

    let arrOfCharacters = Array(trimmedString)
    var modifiedCreditCardString = ""
    if !arrOfCharacters.isEmpty {

        for iterator in 0..<arrOfCharacters.count {
            modifiedCreditCardString.append(arrOfCharacters[iterator])
            if (iterator + 1) % 4 == 0 && iterator + 1 != arrOfCharacters.count {
                modifiedCreditCardString.append(" ")
            }
        }
    }
    self.text = modifiedCreditCardString
    if positionOfEditing != nil {
        if positionOfEditing!%5 == 0 && positionOfEditing! != 0 {
            setCursor(position: positionOfEditing! + (erasing! ? -1 : 1))
        } else {
            setCursor(position: positionOfEditing!)
        }
    }
}

  func setCursor(position: Int) {
     if let text = text, (text.count - 1) > position { }
     let position = self.position(from: beginningOfDocument, offset: position)!
     selectedTextRange = textRange(from: position, to: position)

  }

 }
```

How can I edit this method or create a new one to get this format that I mentioned before:
**XXX-XXXXXXXXX-X-XX**

Comment: I don't think it is worthy to save the caret position when entering a credit card number (or login card). Just implement the deleteBackward method and remove the last digit. The user can always retype the numbers from left to right.

Comment: Oh I see. How can I edit this method to achieve the format Im looking for?  
XXX-XXXXXXXXX-X-XX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is worthy to save the caret position when entering a credit card number (or login card). Just implement the deleteBackward method and remove the last digit. The user can always retype the numbers from left to right. I would also subclass textfield and create a custom field. So first remove all non digits from the field and then switch the number of digits left. If there is from 3 to 11 just insert the first hyphen. If there is 12 insert the first and second hyphens. If there is 13 add the third hyphen as well. Make sure to insert them in reverse other to make your life easier:

```
class LoginField: UITextField {
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        keyboardType = .numberPad
        textAlignment = .center
        autocorrectionType = .no
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }
    override func deleteBackward() {
        text?.removeAll(where: \.isDigit.negated)
        let _ = text?.popLast()
        sendActions(for: .editingChanged)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension LoginField {
    @objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        text?.removeAll(where: \.isDigit.negated)
        text = text?.prefix(15).string
        if let offset = text?.count,
           let startIndex = text?.startIndex {
            switch offset {
            case 3...11:
                if let index = text?.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 3) {
                    text?.insert("-", at: index)
                }
            case 12:
                if let index = text?.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 12) {
                    text?.insert("-", at: index)
                }

                if let index = text?.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 3) {
                    text?.insert("-", at: index)
                }
            case 13...15:
                if let index = text?.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 13) {
                    text?.insert("-", at: index)
                }
                if let index = text?.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 12) {
                    text?.insert("-", at: index)
                }
                if let index = text?.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 3) {
                    text?.insert("-", at: index)
                }
            default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Bool {
    var negated: Bool { !self }
}
```

---

```
extension LosslessStringConvertible {
    var string: String { .init(self) }
}
```

---

```
extension Character {
    var isDigit: Bool { "0"..."9" ~= self }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Leo.
Your method to add "-" is working correctly.

Actually its not an UITextField what Im using, its a custom UITextField that was made by a bank company.

When I try to create a custom UITextField class its not working because I cannot access to this custom UITextField (made by a bank company).

I guess this is the problem why I cannot delete "-" in my customtextfield because i havent ovverided 'deleteBackward' method :(

You think is there another way to do this? I mean delete "-" symbols?